# jQuery and # link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link

```
<a href="#">has a jQuery click handler</a>
```

My jQuery works the way it's supposed to...however the hash # tag is making my browser jump to the top of the page on every click.

Is there any way to get around this? I tried removing the # but it changes my css styling.

Comment: Just an fyi, this isn't a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a `return false;` to the end of your click handler if you want to resolve the issue quick and dirty.

However, return false forces you to exit and virtually stops event propagation.  Since you are using the jquery javascript library, you also have the option of using the `preventDefault()` method instead, which removes the default action and allows the function to keep runnning.

Answer (score 5):

Your click handler should either `return false;` or call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event object.

Example:

```
$('your selector').click(function(e) /* note the parameter e */
{
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `javascript: void false;` instead of `#`. So:

```
<a href="javascript: void false;">has a jQuery click handler</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate the comments above, which are correct, add a return false to the click handler. This would look like:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    ... things to run on click ...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`return false` or call `eventHandler.preventDefault()` on `onclick` event:

```
$('#yourLink').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

or

```
$('#yourLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or change the `href` to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">has a jQuery click handler</a>
```